# How to create contour from NetCDF?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, gdal, contour, netcdf, bathymetry

I have downloaded Bathymetry data from **[GEBCO](http://www.gebco.net/)**. Its in **[NetCDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetCDF)** format. I want to create contour from it. I tried so many tools to convert the file into raster but couldn't do so. How can I create raster from netCDF?

Comment: Have you tried [**this**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Make_NetCDF_Raster_Layer/004300000006000000/)?  If so, I recommend that you include your results as part of your question so we know at least some of what you have tried.

Comment: NetCDF is a standard raster format, so I don't understand what you mean with creating a raster of it. It would help if you could clarify what you tried and what you could not achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have access to the 3D Analyst extension, instead of downloading NetCDF grids, you could download ASCII grids (GEBCO offers both options). You can use the [ASCII 3D to Feature Class](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/ASCII_3D_To_Feature_Class/00q900000041000000/) tool to create a feature layer, and then use the Spline or Krigging tools to create your bathymetric rasters.

Comment: Could you please provide me the link of ASCII grids of GEBCO?

Comment: To get the ASCII grids, you have to download a downloader application. And actually there's an option right in the software to create ArcGIS compatible rasters.

Comment: Link: http://www.gebco.net/data_and_products/grid_display_software/
Warning - the link on that page goes to a British government site, which may trigger a warning about invalid security certificates. I clicked through, and nothing bad happened to me, but I can't make any guarantee that the external site is safe.

Comment: ArcGIS can read NetCDF directly as raster data, so there is no need to modify the dataset by interpolation, kriging etc.: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/A_quick_tour_of_netCDF_data/004600000015000000/

Answer (score 0):

You put the tags "arcgis-desktop" "gdal" so I assume QGIS might be an option too? Depending on the version of netcdf, you can simply load it and then use the usual *Raster -> Extraction -> Contour* workflow.